# Pytest mocking the return value of method called twice within another method of class with different set of values

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm new to pytest and mocking. I need to test a function `process_date`.

```
Class mainclass:

   def __get_date (self,dbname, connectionobject, query):

      # -- retrieve data
      return dataframe

   def process_date(self, date):

      df1 = self.__get_date(self,dbname1, connectionobject1, query1)
      df2 = self.__get_date(self,dbname2, connectionobject2, query2)
      
      # -- logic to compare the above 2 dataframes and I want to test this logic alone
      # the logic basically groups and sums the data using pandas dataframe
      df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
      self.upload(df3)
```

Now I need to mock the return values of `__get_date` function. I don't want to test this function.

I need to have 2 different return_values for `__get_date` function so that df1 and df2 are different.
I need to check whether the grouping logic works without an issue.

My question

1. How to mock the return value of `__get_date` with 2 different dataframes?
2. there is no return for this function it uploads to database. How to validate the dataframe df3 has combined data of df1 and df2?

I just copied the logic part of the function and tested it with sample dataframes. I couldn't find a way to test the function `process_date` as a whole

Comment: You can assign a `MagicMock()` to your methods, and use `side_effect` for different return values. For `.upload,` just check `assert_called_once`